# Prestashop, lost the cache

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

i programming a module for prestashop 1.7.6.2 and try to use the cache, the problem is that this cache is not working, the idea is get the data from an api and save the data in cache, if this data change i ask again, but this is not working, i have this code:

```
public function cotizarEnvio($fromPlace, $toPlace, $weight, $carrier)
    {
        $keyId = "cotizarEnvio_" . $fromPlace . "_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $toPlace) . "_" . $weight . "_" . $carrier;
        if (! \Cache::isStored($keyId))
        {
            try {
                $uri = "https://get.apidata.io/api/v1/prices";
                $response = $this->client->get($uri, [
                    'query' => [
                        'from_place' => $fromPlace,
                        'to_place' => $toPlace,
                        'weight' => $weight,
                        'carrier' => $carrier,
                    ],
                    'headers' => [                   
                        'x-api-key' => 'HereAPIKey',
                    ],
                ]);

                $jsonResponse = $response->json();
                //Si no es success, devolvemos false
                if ($jsonResponse["success"] != true) return false;
                
                if (
                    array_key_exists(0, $jsonResponse["data"]) AND
                    array_key_exists("services", $jsonResponse["data"][0]) AND
                    array_key_exists(0, $jsonResponse["data"][0]["services"]) 
                    )
                    {
                        $responseToBereturned = max(array_column($jsonResponse["data"][0]["services"], "price"));
                        \Cache::store($keyId, $responseToBereturned);
                        return $responseToBereturned;
                    } else return null;
                

            } catch (RequestException $e) {
                $this->handleError($e);
            }
        } else {
            return Cache::retrieve($keyId);
        }
    }
```

my problem is that this cache `if (! \Cache::isStored($keyId))` is not working, i try changing the isStored to store, but the problem continue.

Comment: use cache class without backslash (Cache::isStored($keyId))

Comment: Test die(dump(Cache::retrieve($keyId))); right after store to ensure the cache is stored